# What do you call an action that denotes hard work?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

When you do something that requires courage they call it an *heroic act* or an *act of courage*. What about something that requires hard work?

Example:

> In this digital age, getting your ass off the seat and walking
>   to a physical location of the place is considered a [...].

Comment: a *real inconvenience*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you can use ***[arduous](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/arduous)***, ***[onerous](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/onerous)*** or ***[strenous](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/strenuous)*** task. BBKing's *laborious* task or Josh61 *toil* are also good ones in my opinion (+1).

In line with you *heroic*, perhaps you can also use ***[herculean](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/herculean)*** task as in *"requiring tremendous effort"*

Answer (score 3):

*Getting your ass off the seat and walk[ing] to the physical location of the place is considered:*

- an *effort*
- a *feat*
- an *endeavor*
- a *struggle*
- a *travail*

Answer (score 2):

A term with a strong connotation is ***[toil](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/toil)*** :

> - exhausting labor or effort.
> - a task performed by such effort.

- An example of toil is labor in a field or a factory  for 10 hours a day.

  - *In this digital age, getting your ass off the seat and walk to the physical location of the place is considered hard toil.*

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Laborious?

Derived from the word "labour", meaning work.

A "laborious task" would be considered hard work, complex, detailed or something that requires a lot of concentration or physical work.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to jokingly say that it required *very* hard work you could say

> ***[a labour of Hercules:](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/labor+of+Hercules)*** a very difficult task

(TFD)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give a "burden" connotation to the word, you may call the task a **chore**.

> A *chore* is a duty or task you’re obligated to perform, often one that
>   is unpleasant but necessary. Washing the dishes is a chore, and so is
>   completing a homework assignment you aren’t excited about.